# jQuery css promise done

Tags: jquery, css

Can someone give me an advice:

Example: I Have

```
<div id="breadCrumb" style="width:80%"></div>
```

Not I want to change this `width` to `1oo%` and get the `width` in px on `click`

```
$('#menu_toggle').on('click', function() {
    var cache = $('#breadCrumb');

    cache.css('width', "100%").promise().done(function(){   
        console.log(cache.width());
    });
});
```

But I stil get the `80%` value.

If I click again, only then I get the `100%` value in pixel

The idea was to wait until css is applied and to get the new `width` after

Someone any ideas?

Thank you for help!

Comment: use `setTimeout()` to apply the css and then get the value

Comment: Do you have any transition applied on the `#breadCrumb`? That is, is the width animated from 80% to 100%?

Comment: `css` does its work immediately. You may be looking for `animate`, but you can't animate a percentage.

Comment: nope no transitions or animations, while width changing

Comment: CSS styles might have overridden your inline style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `setTimeout()` to get apply your css and then use it in your code as

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cache = $('#breadCrumb');
    alert(cache.width());
    cache.css('width', "100%")
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert(cache.width());
    },500)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="breadCrumb" style="width:80%"></div>
```

Comment: It has worked with `setTimeout`. Thank you very much! Is it a good practice to use timeouts?

Comment: The `promise` bit above makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

`css` does its work immediately, and so simply

```
cache.css('width', "100%");
console.log("breadCrumb width: " + cache.width());
```

should work, and does on Chrome and Firefox barring something you're not showing us:

```js
$('#menu_toggle').on('click', function() {
    var cache = $('#breadCrumb');

    cache.css('width', "100%");
    console.log("breadCrumb width: " + cache.width());
    console.log("body width: " + $(document.body).width());
});
```

```css
#breadCrumb {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="breadCrumb" style="width:80%"></div>
<input id="menu_toggle" type="button" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But if you need to give the browser a moment to apply the change, you can use `setTimeout` to do that:

```js
$('#menu_toggle').on('click', function() {
    var cache = $('#breadCrumb');

    cache.css('width', "100%");
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("breadCrumb width: " + cache.width());
      console.log("body width: " + $(document.body).width());
    }, 50);
});
```

```css
#breadCrumb {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="breadCrumb" style="width:80%"></div>
<input id="menu_toggle" type="button" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```